# Swift POST query issue

Tags: ios, swift, http-post

I am facing some problem in a POST query; please help. It always sends me a 400 Bad request response. I have checked everything thoroughly but its just not working. Please help.

Code is -

```
struct RegisterService {

var authToken: String = ""
var baseURL = NSURL(string: "")

func getToken(name: String, email: String, password: String, cfmpassword: String, completion: (AuthToken? -> Void)) {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: baseURL!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let params = ["accept":"on", "cfmpassword":"\(cfmpassword)", 
        "email":"\(email)", "name":"\(name)", "password":"\(password)"] 
        as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    do {
        request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    } catch {
        print("Request Unsuccessful")
    }

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        print(request)
        print(data)
        print(response)
        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            switch httpResponse.statusCode {
            case 200:
                // 2. Create JSON object with data
                do {
                    let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let authToken = AuthToken(tokenDictionary: jsonDictionary!)
                    completion(authToken)
                } catch {
                    print("Fetch failed: \((error as NSError).localizedDescription)")
                }
            default:
                print("GET request not successful. HTTP status code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: Not a valid HTTP response")
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
}
```

Comment: Show what is sent and what the server expects

Comment: You're sending JSON request. Are you sure server is expecting JSON request?

Comment: I have also tried sending this in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format, but also does not work.

Comment: You shouldn't be guessing. Either look at the web server code, or if provided by third party, look at their docs. We can't help you debug client code if we (much less, you) don't know what the server is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
let params = ["accept":"on", "cfmpassword":"\(cfmpassword)", "email":"\(email)", "name":"\(name)", "password":"\(password)"] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

let boundary:String = "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"

let body:NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

if params != nil
{
      for (key, value) in params!
      {
            body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
      }
}

body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
request.setValue("\(body.length)", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Length")
request.HTTPBody = body
```

Comment: You're creating body of `multipart/formdata` request, but you never set the `Content-Type` of the header to tell it that you're doing that. (Plus, it's not at all clear whether the OP's web service is expecting multipart request given that he's creating JSON request.) Also, you don't have to set `Content-Length`, as that's set for you.